# Can an Airflow task dynamically generate a DAG at runtime?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an upload folder that gets irregular uploads. For each uploaded file, I want to spawn a DAG that is specific to that file.

My first thought was to do this with a FileSensor that monitors the upload folder and, conditional on presence of new files, triggers a task that creates the separate DAGs. Conceptually:

```
Sensor_DAG (FileSensor -> CreateDAGTask)

|-> File1_DAG (Task1 -> Task2 -> ...)
|-> File2_DAG (Task1 -> Task2 -> ...)
```

In my initial implementation, `CreateDAGTask` was a `PythonOperator` that created DAG globals, by placing them in the global namespace ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44127627/2114580)), like so:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.contrib.sensors.file_sensor import FileSensor
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pathlib import Path

UPLOAD_LOCATION = "/opt/files/uploaded"

# Dynamic DAG generation task code, for the Sensor_DAG below
def generate_dags_for_files(location=UPLOAD_LOCATION, **kwargs):
    dags = []
    for filepath in Path(location).glob('*'):
        dag_name = f"process_{filepath.name}"
        dag = DAG(dag_name, schedule_interval="@once", default_args={
            "depends_on_past": True,
            "start_date": datetime(2020, 7, 15),
            "retries": 1,
            "retry_delay": timedelta(hours=12)
        }, catchup=False)
        dag_task = DummyOperator(dag=dag, task_id=f"start_{dag_name}")

        dags.append(dag)

        # Try to place the DAG into globals(), which doesn't work
        globals()[dag_name] = dag

    return dags
```

The main DAG then invokes this logic via a `PythonOperator`:

```
# File-sensing DAG
default_args = {
    "depends_on_past" : False,
    "start_date"      : datetime(2020, 7, 16),
    "retries"         : 1,
    "retry_delay"     : timedelta(hours=5),
}
with DAG("Sensor_DAG", default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval= "50 * * * *", catchup=False, ) as sensor_dag:

    start_task  = DummyOperator(task_id="start")
    stop_task   = DummyOperator(task_id="stop")
    sensor_task = FileSensor(task_id="my_file_sensor_task",
                             poke_interval=60,
                             filepath=UPLOAD_LOCATION)
    process_creator_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id="process_creator",
        python_callable=generate_dags_for_files,
    )
    start_task >> sensor_task >> process_creator_task >> stop_task
```

But that doesn't work, because by the time `process_creator_task` runs, the globals have already been parsed by Airflow. New globals after parse time are irrelevant.

### Interim solution

Per [Airflow dynamic DAG and task Ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39133376/airflow-dynamic-dag-and-task-ids), <s>I can achieve what I'm trying to do by omitting the `FileSensor` task altogether and just letting Airflow generate the per-file task at each scheduler heartbeat, replacing the Sensor_DAG with just executing `generate_dags_for_files`:</s> Update: Nevermind -- while this does create a DAG in the dashboard, actual execution runs into the ["DAG seems to be missing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472942/dag-seems-to-be-missing) issue:

```py
generate_dags_for_files()
```

This does mean that I can no longer regulate the frequency of folder polling with the `poke_interval` parameter of `FileSensor`; instead, Airflow will poll the folder every time it collects DAGs.

Is that the best pattern here?

### Other related StackOverflow threads

- [Run Airflow DAG for each file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992541/run-airflow-dag-for-each-file) and [Airflow: Proper way to run DAG for each file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60082546/airflow-proper-way-to-run-dag-for-each-file): identical use case, but the accepted answer uses two static DAGs, presumably with different parameters.
- [Proper way to create dynamic workflows in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517798/proper-way-to-create-dynamic-workflows-in-airflow) - accepted answer dynamically creates tasks, not DAGs, via a complicated XCom setup.

Comment: https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/

Comment: @drum I re-read that article; While they do generate DAGs dynamically at parse time, I don't believe any of the examples have an **Airflow task** create a DAG dynamically.

Comment: **@Simon Podhajsky** since python is an interpreter-based language, this can certainly be achieved via **meta-programming**: if your `task` programmatically generates and writes a valid DAG file in Airflow's DAG directory, within a few minutes they will be picked up and will show up on UI. Now it really doesn't have to be as hard as generating `python` code: if you write a python script (DAG-definition file) that generates DAGs (with pre-defined structure / tasks) based on JSON input read from a `Variable`, then just updating `Variable` via your Airflow task would produce new DAG.

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55896121/3679900) comes closest to what you want: he isn't generating new DAG at runtime; but he is adding new downstream `task`s to the DAG at runtime (upstream task updates a `Variable` and causing new downstream tasks to appear)

Comment: but a word of caution here: based on my experience with Airflow (but over and above building and maintaining an ETL-platform), I'd recommend to stay away from this *magic* as much as possible. IMO `DAG`s should be immutable & long-lasting / predictable: **[i]** DAGs shouldn't magically appear and disappear and **[ii]** even worse, `task`s in a DAG shouldn't appear and vanish. Or else, your entire book-keeping (history of DAGs, tasks) would go for a toss and observability / debuggability of system will be compromised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: if the task writes where the `DagBag` reads from, yes, but it's best to avoid a pattern that requires this. **Any DAG you're tempted to custom-create in a task should probably instead be a static, heavily parametrized, conditionally-triggered DAG.** [y2k-shubham provides an excellent example of such a setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63421315/2114580), and I'm grateful for his guidance in the comments on this question.

That said, here are the approaches that would accomplish what the question is asking, **no matter how bad of an idea it is**, in the increasing degree of ham-handedness:

- If you dynamically generate DAGs from a Variable ([like so](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/)), modify the Variable.
- If you dynamically generate DAGs from a list of config files, add a new config file to wherever you're pulling config files from, so that a new DAG gets generated on the next DAG collection.
- Use something like Jinja templating to write a new Python file in the `dags/` folder.

To retain access to the task after it runs, you'd have to keep the new DAG definition stable and accessible on future dashboard updates / `DagBag` collection. Otherwise, [the Airflow dashboard won't be able to render much about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420667/can-airflow-persist-access-to-metadata-of-short-lived-dynamically-generated-task)

Comment: To anyone reading this, the answer above is wrong about Dynamic DAGs being a bad idea. Hear from the inventor of Airflow instead: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fvu2oFyFCT0

Answer (score 0):

Airflow is suited for building DAGs dynamically; as pointed it out by its creator:
https://youtu.be/Fvu2oFyFCT0?t=411 p.s. thanks to @Yiannis for the video reference

Here is an example of how this could be accomplished:
https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/dynamically-generating-dags