# Changing Dependencies of the task using UI in apache airflow

Tags: airflow

Is there a way to set the tasks dependency from the UI itself instead of defining it in a DAG file. I know we can set **dependencies** like `task1 >> task2 >> task3`. But, can I do the same using the localhost **`webserver UI.`**

Answer (score 2):

**[Q]** Does Airflow natively support UI-based DAG editing?

**[A]** No

---

**[Q]** Can the same 'effect' be achieved?

**[A]** Yes

If you cook-up a *DAG-builder* code that (say) parses a JSON / YAML stored in Airflow `Variable` (which contain information of what `DAG`s, `operator`s to create and how to link them together) to generate `DAG`s, then by editing those `Variable`s (from UI itself), you'll be able to modify the structure of your DAG

Some good references are

- [`etsy/boundary-layer`](https://codeascraft.com/2018/11/14/boundary-layer%E2%80%89-declarative-airflow-workflows/)
- [`dag-factory`](https://medium.com/@ajbosco/introducing-dag-factory-a107cc598868)

---

**[Q]** Should this be done (recommended practise)?

**[A]** As long as the DAGs that your are generating in this way are *immutable* (their structure doesn't keep on changing every now and then), it is fine. And while it might be enticing to have dynamically modifying structure (sounds very cool / powerful), in my opinion it should be avoided since that would compromise system's sanity (system will become difficult to reason about, debugg-ability will be hurt)

---

Further reads

- [Astronomer.io: Dynamically Generating DAGs in Airflow](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/dynamically-generating-dags/)
- (advanced stuff) [Comment in Can an Airflow task dynamically generate a DAG at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962386/can-an-airflow-task-dynamically-generate-a-dag-at-runtime#comment111360609_62962386)